# CSS Grids doesn't work on Mozilla and IE for some reason (even with the prefixes)

Tags: css, css-grid, autoprefixer

I just made [this site](http://grid.lucasdebelder.be/) using CSS Grids system in Chrome. It all looked perfectly how I wanted it then I added prefixes with an online tool/generator.

https://autoprefixer.github.io/
and
http://pleeease.io/play/

If I look up [CSS Grids on 'CanIuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid)' it shows up that it should work on all browsers.

So far it works on Safari, Chrome, Android Chrome and Opera.

What is causing this problem that my grid system doesn't display correctly on Mozilla and IE?

For example the code is as following with both `-ms` prefixes.

```
display: -ms-grid; //IE and Mozilla prefixes..
display: grid; //Chrome

-ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[6];
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
```

Comment: Please try to add a minimal example so we can reproduce the problem. Otherwise it might marked as off-topic question.

Comment: Ok, I will add some code

Comment: There is no mozilla browser, you mean Firefox. Also make sure FF is up to date.

Comment: Even with IE *"**Partial** support in IE refers to supporting an older version of the specification."* amd you don't state which version of IE.

Comment: Also, have you prefixed **every** grid property...I can see some in IE that are not `grid-row` for instance...and even then the `1/1` notation does not seem to be acceptable to IE.

Comment: Strange when I add my CSS (http://grid.lucasdebelder.be/css/style.css) into the generator it actually doesn't give me all the CSS prefixes.. Why is that? @cloned

Comment: if you look at the release site of this generator you will see that the last update was done last year. grids were introduced this year. So to answer your question: This autoprefixer is out of date.

Comment: @cloned Yes you are right! I thought it was something like that. I will update the 200 lines of code then myself